# jmsMessage.setJMSMessageID(...) not working? (How to set customised messageID to JMS message ?)

Tags: jms, hornetq

I want to `setJMSMessageID` in sequence 1,2,3.... while sending a JMS Message in HornetQ. But whenever I tried to set my customized MessageID to JMS message, at the consumer end the MessageID of the same JMS message is different.

While doing so I found that JMS MessageID has some specific format. So how do I set my customized MessageID?

Answer (score 1):

According to the API docs,

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSMessageID%28java.lang.String%29

JMS providers set the messageID field when a message is sent.

You cannot override the messageID set by the JMS provider with your own JMSMessageID before the message is sent. Is there a particular reason why you want to set your own message ID?

if you are looking to monitor a sequence, maybe you can consider storing such information inside the content of the message itself, or as a message property.

Comment: yes you can set a customized JMSMessageID, but that can only be done after the message is sent. This can happen on the sender's side after the message is sent, or on the receiver's side after the message is received. Do take note that the receiver will never be able to receive a customized JMSMessageID no matter what.

Comment: so there is no point of setting customised JMS messageID after sending message if consumer will not read the same messageID .. actually my requirement is same msgID (Customised) is being set as a correlationid of the response msg.....how do i achieve it ?

Comment: You can't manipulate the JMSMessageID at all. Try setting the content that you require inside the JMS Message body itself. For example, you could put the content: "custom-id: 12345" and then read this value from the message body. This way, you don't have to touch the JMSMessageID header at all.

Comment: because if we cant manipulate JMS MessageID then they should not specify api for setting MessageId (setJMSMessageID())...there should be some usage of api setJMSMessageId(..)....

Comment: yes i am sure you cant manipulate JMSMessageID at all. see the javadoc link i provided above. this is clearly stated in the javadocs. the API setJMSMessageID() was provided for JMS providers to use to set the messageID just before sending the message, and not for developers.. unless you wish to modify the JMSMessageID after the message was received, which is not what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

I am using setJMSCorrelationID for setting custom ID. ON the receiver end, you can use getJMSCorrelationID to retrieve the same..

Comment: Yes, this is the way!